# Scalable Database Plan and Server Selection for Big Amount of Data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, backend, devops

I started to work on a startup, where I am goign to write backend. It is my first time that I need to work with this big project and I wanted to ask a few questions to see what is the best practice. I will explain the workflow and informations first than ask for your valuable ideas.
The project is aiming to connect multiple pharmaceutical companies(at most 10) with many (at most 20.000) pharmacies. Pharmacies are supposed to upload screenshots or pdf files, and I need to gather information from these files. Every pharmacy might upload at most 100 screenshots and maybe a few pdf files, but they might do this process for different pharmaceutical companies. Lets say a pharmacy uploads 100 ss and 2 pdfs for company a, company b and company c, so 300 images and 6 pdfs total. Also, reading from pdf or using ocr system for images takes time. Every pdf will have information(Transaction data) about 50 Drugs. I will have Drugs Table and also Transactions table. Every Drug has on avarage 7 transaction. I feel like Transactions table will be huge after sometime and it would be costly to run queries on that big table.
Here are my questions

1)I am planning to use MySQL, would it be enough to serve my purpose?

2)Should I have a seperated database for each company or it is better idea to keep everything in one company.

3)What is the best practice to implement Drugs and Transactions table. Easist way is just to use a foreignkey, but as I told, after some time transactions table will be so big, so maybe there is a better way to plan it.

4)Should I go with a dedicated server or choose a service like AWS.As I said reading from pdf or using ocr takes time.

5)Which storege option would be reasonable for this project. Again, dedicated server or services like AWS storeage.

6)When I read a drug information, it will have drug data and also around 7 transactions. So i need to write to database 8 times per drug. Could there be less costly option?

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking of MySQL:

- Thousands of rows is "tiny"; millions is "medium-sized".
- A table with a billion rows has some challenges, but it is do-able.
- My best advice is to plan on *rewriting the entire schema and code in about 4 months*.  With that advice, you can hastily build *something*, then learn why it is not optimal; then rebuild it.
- Use as many tables as you need.  (It sounds like you might need a few dozen.  A thousand tables would probably indicate that you are doing something wrong.)
- Consider storing images, pdfs, etc in files, not in tables.  Then put the file path in a table.

Reading a PDF should be done only once, then capture the OCR'd result into a text file (or `MEDIUMTEXT` column).  After that, you can write code (with or without SQL) to parse it and copy the important data into the database.  *And* you can re-do that when you find that the parsing was not adequate.